# Android app Custom Fonts getting totally ignored on phone

Tags: java, android, fonts

I've got a android app that was using a custom font. The font was a truetype font in the assets/fonts and applied individually to TextViews with view.setTypeface() method, all is working fine.

I've now setup a new app project and again I'm trying to use a custom font, this time I'm trying to implement Font Awesome, looks great inside android studio and is working fine there but when I debug on the phone the font just doesn't show up, all I get is squares with crosses in them. So I tried the same font I was using before, again the font doesn't change on the phone. I've tried doing it via putting the font is res/font and using android:fontFamily attribute as well and it still will not show up on the phone.

The only major difference between the two projects is that in the new one I have a View (Footer) which contains a header/footer and the mainActivity view which inherits from Footer. The actual font is only used on the footer view at the moment for a few buttons, I've also tried on TextView (using a custom TextView too). I've tried setting the font on the footer and from within the mainActiviy, again no success.

As far as I can tell this project is ignoring all set fonts when I try to use it on the phone, but I know that this phone does support at least one of the fonts I've tried.

I've been banging my head against the wall all day with this and nothing seems to work. I would share some of the code but unfortunately android studio just crashed (again).

Comment: Are there any differences in the dependencies (e.g., `appcompat-v7` versions? one using `appcompat-v7` and one not?)?

Comment: Look to the version of `appcompat-v7`, you can test using `AppCompatTextView` and then try to see if you have `app:fontFamily` available

Comment: Original project uses appcompat-v7:22 new one uses appcompat-v7:25.

Comment: Just tried using AppCompatTextView. Didnt make any difference, still not applying the font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extmkv's comment was correct, using android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView instead of TextView or Button allows it to show the font correctly, so long as its also set using View.setTypeFace() method as well.

Thanks!